# Framework7 $$.ajax CORS error but not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, cors, html-framework-7

After many hours of fighting with CORS error when using Framework $$.ajax I decided to turn to the community for help.

I'm playing with PhoneGap and Framework7. I try to call API on my .local domain and I'm getting CORS error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://domain.local/api/call. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).". I've enabled CORS header in .htaccess and I can see Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" header in response when call it using any REST client, but Framework7 $$.ajax still doesn't work. I've "crossDomain: true" in ajax configuration, but still doesn't work.

When I use jQuery $.ajax all works fine in browser but not on mobile device in PhoneGap app simulator.

So I have jQuery working at least in browser, I see Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" header in response headers but Framework7 doesn't work.

Or maybe You guys could suggest other set PhoneGap + other framework to build app.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `but still doesn't work` - what errors or messages are you getting once you've fixed the CORS issue? It sounds like you're saying you're still getting CORS errors, but it's a) unclear and b) unlikely that you get CORS issues using one library while another library doesn't - they all, in the end, use the same javascript methods to get data from a server, so would be subject to the same rules

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X. So Framework7 $$.ajax causes CORS error, JavaScript jQuery $.ajax doesn't. I now this sounds odd but that's what I'm getting. I work with jQuery for last 6 years and I've never had this problem.  So I've even tried XMLHttpRequest(). Unfortunately this doesn't work either. What I've noticed is that when I use jQuery $.ajax PhoneGap runs it through some proxy, but it doesn't when I use Framework7 $$.ajax. I need to add that all those attempts aro done in PhoneGap browser simulator. And in addition jQuery works in browser but doesn't on mobile device. Hop this is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this working. So, long story short. After hours of trying I went for 5k run, took a shower and started from scratch. I added each element and then tested it. Now I have Framework7 working in browser and on a mobile device. I think that it was the order of implementing libraries. So now it is:

1. cordova.js
2. framework7.min.js
3. my custom scripts

In my custom scripts I added

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
    // your code
}
```

I'm not getting CORS error any more. I didn't change any configuration on my server.

Obviously, browser version works with .local domain as I can set it in my hosts file. Mobile version doesn't work with local domain, but as I have my API already on .com domain I don't mind.

I hope this will help others.